# prepared statement "fooplan" already exists

Tags: postgresql

Running the following SQL statement:

```
 create or replace procedure test_insert_prepare2(howmany int)
        language plpgsql 
        as $$
        declare counter integer:=0;
        declare note int;
        begin
        prepare fooplan(int) as 
        insert into procedure_testing_table values($1, $2);
        select count(*) into strict note from procedure_testing_table;
        while counter < howmany loop
        counter := counter +1;
        note := note +1;
        execute fooplan(note,'testing_prepare');
        end loop;
        end;
        $$
```

always shows an error:

```
ERROR:  prepared statement "fooplan" already exists
```

How could I use prepare statement correctly in a while loop?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-deallocate.html

Comment: Additionally: instead of `while counter < howmany loop  counter := counter +1; ...` you can to use `for counter in 0..howmany-1 loop ...`

Comment: Note, `declare` starts a block to declare variables. There is no need to start a new declare block for each variable.

Comment: You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for this to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements live until the end of the database session or until you explicitly deallocate them, so the second invocation of the function will cause this error.

But it is not necessary to use a prepared statement here, because PL/pgSQL automatically caches execution plans. So use a plain `INSERT` inside the loop, it will be just as efficient.